# Group of stars moving

Tags: astronomy

I know that this might not be the right place to ask this but maube someone of astronomy can help.

A few days ago i saw a group of stars moving in the sky like a worm. This happenned again 2 days later.

I was looking in the internet for the name of this phenomenon but i didnt go anything.

Does someone know the name of this phenomenon?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what 'moving like a worm' actually means? A diagram perhaps?

Comment: How many stars?  What time of day? (9:00 pm?  midnight?  3:00 am?)  How fast?  How long did the phenomenon persist?  How high up from the horizon?  Where did you see this, roughly?

Comment: I am not about to migrate this question to another Stack until it is clarified.

Comment: If it is clarified, it's probably going to be on topic here anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Perseids

If you have seen a group of several bright objects moving in the same direction across the night sky on several successive nights, it may be a part of the Perseid meteor shower which is active around now.

> The [Perseid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseids) meteor shower will peak overnight tonight (Aug. 11 and 12) as Earth passes through the long trail left by Comet Swift-Tuttle

Comment: Thanks! I heard about that and I search for perseids stars but I was looking to see something like I've seen on those nights (I search also on Youtube...no results)